# Invariant spaces of two linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let there be $S:V \to V$ and $T:V \to V$ linear transformations ($dimV=n$), and let there be $W$ a invariant subspace of both $S$ and $T$.
Is it true that $TS=ST$? Can it be proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can't be proven. Consider:

$$T=\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$S=\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ 0 && 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$W=\{\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}t : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

$W$ is invariant subspace of $S$ and $T$, but:

$$TS=\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2 \\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$ST=\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ 0 && 0\end{bmatrix}$$